# Count occurrences of a sub string in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table which stores information of a lot of twitter tweets including the tweet text and the screen name of the user who tweeted the tweet. The tweets contain hashtags (starting with #), I want to count the number of hashtags that a specific user has tweeted:

```
tweet_id |                       tweet_text                           | screen_name    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1 | #hashtag1 #otherhashtag2 #hashtag3 some more text          | tweeter_user_1 |
       2 | some text #hashtag1 #hashtag4 more text                    | tweeter_user_2 |
       3 | #hashtag5 #hashtag1 @not a hashtag some#nothashtag         | tweeter_user_1 |
       4 | #hashtag1 with more text                                   | tweeter_user_3 |
       5 | #otherhashtag2 #hashtag3,#hashtag4 more text               | tweeter_user_1 |
```

If I were to count the hashtags of tweeter_user_1, the result i expect is 8, if i wanted the hashtags of tweeter_user_3 it should return 1. How can I do it assuming that my table name is tweets.

I tried this: `SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tweets WHERE( LENGTH( REPLACE( tweet_text, '#%', '@') = 0 ) ) AND screen_name = 'tweeter_user_1'` but it didn't work

I would be happy if the result of tweeter_user_1 was 9 too :D

Comment: If it's just the `number` of hashtags you want, then something like: `SELECT SUM(LENGTH(tweet_text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tweet_text, '#', ''))) FROM tweets WHERE screen_name = 'tweeter_user_1'` should work.

Comment: In fact, you are going to have a difficult time not matching some#nothashtag - if possible @JYelton's suggestion is a good one - precalculate on storage - it's never going to change.

Comment: Yeah, that's why i updated the post with "It's ok if i get a count of 9", JYelton idea is very good, but the table is already huge and i only needed this script to calculate the number of hashtags of one person that we detected abusing the system. Plus the application will be over in 3 or 4 weeks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should give you a list of screen_names and the total count of all hashtags they use.

```
SELECT  foo.screen_name, SUM(foo.counts) FROM 
  (
    SELECT screen_name, 
           LENGTH( tweet_text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tweet_text, '#', '')) AS counts 
    FROM tweet_table 
  ) as foo 
GROUP BY  foo.screen_name
```

But.... it's a nasty query if the table is huge.  I might specify a specific users in the inner select if you just need counts for a single user.  Like this:

```
SELECT  foo.screen_name, SUM(foo.counts) FROM 
 (
    SELECT screen_name, 
         LENGTH( tweet_text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(tweet_text, '#', '')) AS counts 
    FROM tweet_table WHERE  screen_name = 'tweeter_user_1' 
 ) as foo 
GROUP BY  foo.screen_name
```

Comment: I think it has some kind of mistake, i keep getting an error message when I run this script: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE screen_name = 'LozanoXiomii') AS counts FROM tweet_table ) as foo GROUP

Comment: @Tales yup, put the where in the wrong place... updated query in exampl

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how often you need to run the query, you could be causing MySQL to spend a lot of CPU time parsing and reparsing the `tweet_text` column. I would strongly recommend adding a `hashtag_qty` column (or similar) and store the count of hashtag elements there when you populate the row to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it is a very good idea and i will keep it for future reference as we probably will start a few more contests using tweeter hashtags, and our magazine has a high number of people following us.