# Get count of substring of column value in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table.

---

id | value

1  | A B,B C

2 | C D,A B

3 | B C,A E

---

I want to know count of substring.

---

sub | count

A B | 2

B C | 2

C D | 1

A E | 1

---

How do I get this result by using sql query in Mysql?

Comment: Do you have a reference table with distinct values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurrences of a sub string in a MySQL column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736459/count-occurrences-of-a-sub-string-in-a-mysql-column)