# Count occurrences of character in a string using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

Example Words: a, akkka, akokaa, kokoko, kakao, oooaooa, kkako, kakaoa

I need the regexp witch gives words with 2 or less 'a' but not the words without 'a'

Result: a, akka, kakao, oooaooa, kkako

Ok actually I am using:

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary_gr WHERE word REGEXP 'λ{2,3}' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

this returns 0 lines there are words with 2 λ's and 3 λ's

Comment: superset: string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
select *  
from table  
where  LENGTH(name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(name, 'a', '')) between 1 and 2
```

Updated to use between.

Comment: Example: baaa => b. LENGTH(b) <= 1. But original string contains more than 2 'a's.

Comment: @simon that is a completely different query than what I am using.  Further why are you taking the length of `b`?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Why? You first replace all 'a's with ''. After that you retrieve the length of the string without 'a's. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @Simon you were correct, I missed the initial subtraction, good eye :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo Now it's nearly perfect :) it must be greater than zero. You can use the BETWEEN-Operator with the operands 1 and 2

Comment: @Simon ah yes, now to think how to avoid invoke length(replace) twice

Comment: @Pavlos there we go, use of between

Comment: @Simon there we go that should suffice now.

Comment: @Simon I am not sure if this is better or worse than regex in the general case.

Comment: @Woot4Moo should be in O(LENGTH(word)), which is pretty acceptable. Anyhow, I'm not sure if Regex is always in O(LENGTH(word)).

Comment: I m using UTF8 so Length(α) = 2 so it work with between 2 and 4

Comment: Brilliant. Love it. I'm gonna KILL in wordfeud! utf(ix): `between 1*length('α') and 2*length('α')`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what MySQL supports in terms of lookaround assertions, but the following will do the trick:

```
^(?=.*a.*a?.*)(?!.*a.*a.*a.*).*$
```

We have a lookahead assertion that matches 1 or 2 `a` characters in the string. Then we have a negative lookahead that disregards 3 or more `a`s anywhere in the string. Then the final pattern just matches the whole string, providing the first two assertions are satisfied.

If MySQL doesn't support lookarounds, then @Woot4Moo's answer would be the way to go.

Answer (score -3):

Quick and dirty:

```
Select word, number_of_as From
(
 Select 'akkka' word, REGEXP_COUNT('akkka', 'a') number_of_as From dual
)
Where number_of_as <= 2
/
```

Comment: `REGEXP_COUNT` is Oracle (11g and later), not MySQL.

Comment: Look here-MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual - Regular Expressions:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: There is no mention of `REGEXP_COUNT` in the MySQL manual (the page you linked), nor any function like it. As I say, it's an Oracle function that was introduced in 11g: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm