# SQL: String that contains 1, 2,3,4 or 5 characters

Tags: sql

I need to get data from database, that has a table called "our_videos", and a column called "champion" must contain a data with string that have character $.
My current SQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM our_videos WHERE champion LIKE '%$%'
```

but it gives me data that looks like this: .....$.....$....$....$... but I only want a data that looks like this .....$..... Sorry if there are not enough needed data, just ask and I'll add if required.

Here as asked some sample data:

Table:

id|champion

---

54|"Something$Something"

55|"Something$Something$something"

56|"Something$Something$Something$something"

57|"Something"

With SQL command that I wrote I'd get rows with ID 54,55,56 but I want to get only row with id 54

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add sample data?

Comment: Updated with some sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe should you indicate the number of occurrences of $ you're looking for... [Like in this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14157526/1720332).

Answer (score 8):

You need a single **$**?

```
SELECT * 
FROM our_videos 
WHERE champion LIKE '%$%'
  AND champion NOT LIKE '%$%$%'
```

Comment: Okay I'll test it in a couple of minutes and accept if everything will work