# how to calculate tf-idf?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, tf-idf

i have a problem, i cant calculate the tf-idf with my actual code.

This is an example of tf-idf:

```
$tfidf = $term_frequency *  // tf
        log( $total_document_count / $documents_with_term, 2); // idf
```

I have the total documents, but i need $documents_with_term and $term_frequency.

This is my actual code:

```
$frase = htmlspecialchars($_GET['frase'], ENT_NOQUOTES);

$sssql = $server_link->query("SELECT uDR.webTitulo, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords, uDR.weburl, SUM(uDR.priority) as SPriority
FROM (

(SELECT s1.webTitulo, s1.webDescripcion, s1.weburl, s1.webkeywords, $a as priority FROM webs s1 WHERE MATCH (webTitulo) AGAINST ('$frase'))

UNION

(SELECT s2.webTitulo, s2.webDescripcion, s2.weburl, s2.webkeywords, $b as priority FROM webs s2 WHERE MATCH (webkeywords) AGAINST ('$frase*' IN BOOLEAN MODE))

UNION

(SELECT s3.webTitulo, s3.webDescripcion, s3.weburl, s3.webkeywords, $c as priority FROM webs s3 WHERE MATCH (webDescripcion) AGAINST ('$frase'))) uDR

GROUP BY uDR.webTitulo, uDR.weburl, uDR.webDescripcion, uDR.webkeywords

ORDER BY SPriority DESC ");

$totalRows = $sssql->num_rows; //This is the $total_document_count
```

I have the $total_document_count, but i dont know how extract the TF and $documents_with_term.

How i can extract them?.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030234/how-to-search-a-corpus-to-find-frequency-of-a-string/24374866#24374866

Answer (score 0):

- In your example $totalRows would be the documents with term.
- Total document count would be SELECT COUNT(*) total_documents FROM webs
- Term frequency is a little more difficult to figure out with SQL. see: [Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)