# Mysql "like" get most relevant multiple searchwords results

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-like

I want a query that would return most close to the keywords from the search field. I search in 4 columns. title, description, author, take_place.
This is the current code, that returns results from all columns. i want a more specific search result.

```
$v = explode(' ', strtolower($searchwords));
if($c != ''){ $and = 'AND cat_id = '.$c; }
foreach($v as $val){
  $query parts[] = "'%".mysql_real_escape_string($val)."%'";
}
$title = implode(' OR title LIKE ', $query_parts);
$desc = implode(' OR desc LIKE ', $query_parts);
$author = implode(' OR author LIKE ', $query_parts);
$take_place = implode(' OR take_place LIKE ', $query_parts);

$sql_res=mysql_query("select * from nt_seminars where ((title like {$title}) or
 (description like {$description}) or (author like {$author}) or 
(take_place like {$take_place})) $and ORDER BY date;");
```

This query returns every result that has any of the words, i want to retrieve most relevant combo search keywords. it would be like:

if results in author and take_place, retrieve those only. Somehow, replace the OR with AND, but then it wouldn't return any results at all. This query is triggered by ajax.

**Got something better, but still not what i wanted..**

```
$q = $_POST['searchword'];
  $arraySearch = explode(" ", $_POST['searchword']);
  // table fields to search
  $arrayFields = array(0 => "title", 1 => "city", 2=> "author");
  $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);
  while ($a < $countFields)
   {
    while ($b < $countSearch)
    {
      $query = $query."$arrayFields[$a] LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
      $b++;
      if ($b < $countSearch)
      {
        $query = $query." AND ";
      }
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
    if ($a < $countFields)
    {
      $query = $query.") OR (";
    }
  }
  $query = $query.")";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query);

  if(mysql_num_rows($query_result) < 1)
  {
   echo '<span class="no-borders">No results found</span>';
  }
  else
  {
   echo '<ul class="list-group no-radius m-b-none m-t-n-xxs list-group-lg no-border">';
    // output list of articles
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
    {
//output loop
    }
  }
```

This returns keywords found only at one of columns. I need an elimination type of query..

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field

Comment: I want to search in multiple columns. if found hit on "author" get all rows that contain author="value", BUT if found hit on author="michael" and take_place="Greece", show me all these rows. The more hits are found, the more relevant the query will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND IT.!
in order to search on multiple columns, with multiple keywords using ajax keyup function i used

```
    $table = "nt_seminars";
// explode search words into an array
$q = $_POST['searchword'];
if($_GET[cat_id] != ''){ $and = 'AND cat_id='.$_GET[cat_id]; }
      $arraySearch = explode(" ", $_POST['searchword']);
  // table fields to search
  $arrayFields = array(0 => "title", 1 => "city", 2=> "author");
  $countSearch = count($arraySearch);
  $a = 0;
  $b = 0;
  $query = "SELECT *, CONCAT_WS(' ',title,author,city) FROM ".$table." WHERE (";
  $countFields = count($arrayFields);
  while ($a < $countFields)
  {
    while ($b < $countSearch)
    {
      $query = $query."CONCAT_WS(' ',title,author,city) LIKE '%$arraySearch[$b]%'";
      $b++;
      if ($b < $countSearch)
      {
        $query = $query." AND ";
      }
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
    if ($a < $countFields)
    {
      $query = $query.") OR (";
    }
  }
  $query = $query." $and AND visible = 1 ORDER BY date desc)";
  $query_result = mysql_query($query) or die ($e = mysql_error());

  if(mysql_num_rows($query_result) < 1)
  {
   echo '<span class="no-borders">No results found</span>';
  }
  else
  {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
    {
      // output whatever you want here for each search result
    }
  }
```

basically, it is all about, combining all the columns, separating them with a space, so as to retrieve results by letters and not words(FULLTEXT).
i used it for live search outputting to list
Hope that helps!