# how to count specific character in specific field SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to make a query in MySQL that counts the number of appearances of a character in specific field

for example:

```
Class          | ID 
============================
d              |1          
c;g;i;m        |2          
r;e            |3
```

final resault should be:

```
Class          | ID        | NumOf; (to be added)
==========================================================
d              |1          | 0
c;g;i;m        |2          | 3
r;e            |3          | 1
```

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)

Answer (score 3):

So that is with [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace):

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(Class) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(Class, ';', '')) AS result FROM t
```

That is: count how many characters are before replacement and after.

Comment: +1 to counter the nob who downvoted you by **5 times**.