# MySQL multi string occurence in string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this:

```
-----------
ID | Value
-----------
1  | AAAA
2  | ABCD
3  | AADC
4  | ABBD
```

I am trying to figure out how to return the number of times a string occurs in each of the Value.

So, if I want to count of time 'A' and 'B'appears, the sql statement will return like this:

```
    -------------------
    ID | Value | Count
    ------------------- 
    1  | AAAA  |   0 
    2  | ABCD  |   1 
    3  | AADC  |   0 
    4  | ABBD  |   2 
    5  | ABBB  |   3 
    6  | AABB  |   3 
    7  | AAAB  |   3
    8  | AABC  |   2
    9  | DBCA  |   1
   10  | CBAA  |   2
   11  | BDAB  |   2
```

Example: The value is "ACBB" and the chars I want to search is 'A' and 'B'. And the result is 2. First we search 'A' and 'B'. When we replace first 'A' and 'B', the value will be "CB" ('C' and 'B') and the counter will be 1. If there is one more 'A' or 'B', it will be count. So the counter for the example is 2, because there is one 'B'. If there is 2 'B', the result is 3.

Is there any way to do this? I do not want to use php, vb, etc. Just MySQL

Comment: First, the value must match 'A' and 'B'. And if there is other value 'A' or 'B' match then it will be counting. So the step is (A and B), (A or B), (A or B) = 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)

Comment: @Leandro . It is not the duplicate. Check the count of 6th row `AABB = 3`. . Its not simply counting occurrence of a particular character. Good logic is involved here . +1 for good question

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Oracle, I hope it works in MySQL too:

```
select value,
  case when value not like '%A%' or value not like '%B%' THEN 0
  else (LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, 'A', '')) +  LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, 'B', '')) - 1)
  end case from test;
```

Of course if your table has a different name, you have to change it in your query.

Comment: A and B which I want to search is not a string ("AB"), but 2 chars 'A' and 'B'. And according your answer, when the value is AAAA, the counter is 3. The first rule is, the value must contains 2 chars ('A' and 'B') which I want to search, wherever its position. If it is does not contains one of char which I want to search, then the counter is zero

Comment: Also we need to divide the resulting number by `needle length` as it doesn’t work correctly with needle string length greater than 1 character

Comment: @Slocky : Sorry, in this case I misunderstood your question. The other part: AAAA gives back 0 in Oracle, that should be the same in MySQL.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. The first case condition has been changed, now it makes sure, that whether A, or B is missing you got 0. I tested it inOracle, and gives exactly the values you wrote in your example above. Please try it in MySQL because I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, Value,    
  CASE 
   WHEN ROUND (( LENGTH(Value) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Value, "AB", ""))) / LENGTH("AB")) = 0 THEN 0
   WHEN ROUND (( LENGTH(Value) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Value, "AB", ""))) / LENGTH("AB")) = 1 THEN
   (ROUND (( LENGTH(Value) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Value, "A", ""))) / LENGTH("A"))  +
   (ROUND (( LENGTH(Value) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( Value, "B", ""))) / LENGTH("B")) - 1
 END
AS Count    
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: every char position in value string can be random ("DACB", "BCDA", etc). It is not always "AB"..