# MySQL String separation by comma operator

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have String `asdasdwdfef,rgrgtggt,weef` and i want output like in table format as shown below

```
id      decription
1       asdasdwdfef
2       rgrgtggt
3       weef
```

For this i created a procedure
here is my procedure

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE Procedure Split(_RowData text, _Delimeter text)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _Iterator INT default 1;
    DECLARE _FoundIndex INT;
    DECLARE _Data varchar(255);
    SET _FoundIndex = LOCATE(_Delimeter,_RowData);
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _RtnValue;
    CREATE temporary TABLE _RtnValue(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description text, primary key(ID));
    WHILE _FoundIndex > 1 DO
        INSERT INTO _RtnValue (description)
        SELECT
        _Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(_RowData, 1, _FoundIndex - 1)));
        set _RowData = SUBSTRING(_RowData, _FoundIndex + LENGTH(_Delimeter) / 2, LENGTH(_RowData));
        SET _Iterator = _Iterator + 1;
        SET _FoundIndex = LOCATE(_Delimeter, _RowData);
    END WHILE;
    INSERT INTO _RtnValue(description) SELECT _Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(_RowData));
    select * from _RtnValue;
END
```

But when i execute it by using following command

```
call Split('asdasdwdfef,rgrgtggt,weef', ',');
```

it gives me the following output:

```
id      decription
1       NULL
2       NULL
3       NULL
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue.
I am using MySQL.

Comment: Can't get it to work on sqlfiddle, but should you not just loose the _data in your insert statement? IE   INSERT INTO _RtnValue (description)
        SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(_RowData, 1, _FoundIndex - 1)));

Comment: @user1515791 I declare my _data "DECLARE _Data varchar(255);" and error is out but the output is NULL.

Comment: @user1515791 i just update my post please check it again.

Comment: Maybe interesting? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/007e3/4. You may need to copy the code to your IDE. It uses functions to parse the string. And a 'table of integers' to generate the rows.

Comment: @RyanVincent why not post that as an answer with explanation?

Comment: @RyanVincent can you just explain why my description values NULL.

Comment: @RyanVincent I see your answer but i think its too lengthy. First you create two function then you create one SP. But i want this in very simple way. I appreciate if you solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

First create new function

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1), delim, '');
```

Then create stored procedure

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE Split(in fullstr varchar(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT Default 0 ;
    DECLARE str VARCHAR(255);

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_temp_table;
    CREATE temporary TABLE my_temp_table(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, description text, primary key(ID));

    simple_loop: LOOP
        SET a=a+1;
        SET str=SPLIT_STR(fullstr,",",a);
        IF str='' THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
        END IF;
        #Do Inserts into temp table here with str going into the row
        insert into my_temp_table (description) values (str);
   END LOOP simple_loop;
   select * from my_temp_table;
END
```

After that when i call it by `call Split('asas,d,sddf,dfd');` it gives me the output that what i want.

Thanx for every suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements: split a 'delimited' column into rows (a table).

Why? You can use all the SQL Aggregate functions to process the rows.

[Working SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/007e3/4)

Related questions that use this code:

- [Count number of unique characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29969124/3184785)
- [Can I resolve this with pure mysql? (joining on ';' separated values in a column)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33806675/3184785)

I chose to use:

- table of integers (integersequence) which when 'inner joined' or 'cross joined' (same thing) to another table will generate rows which are certain to have a unique sequence number starting from 1. This is just using what RDBMS engines are required to do.
- why a table of integers?: It is small and will get loaded into the cache. It is easy to understand.
- Rather than have lots of code in the query that obscures what it actually does. I use functions that do one job. It simplifies the main query and can be tested and checked separately. I am only concerned about ease of maintenance and understanding at this point.

The example here is for one string. However, It can be easily expanded to a table of delimited strings of various sizes. The 'cross join' will create all the possible options of index starting from 1 when joining to `integersequence` (i really need to use another name :-/).

So, the query:

```
SET @StrToParse = "asdasdwdfef,rgrgtggt,weef";

/* example */
select integerseries.id,
       count_in_set(@StrToParse, ','),
       value_in_set(@StrToParse, ',', integerseries.id)
from integerseries
where integerseries.id <= count_in_set(@StrToParse, ',');
```

The output:

```
PositionOfString, CountOfCommaDelimitedStrings, StringAtThatPosition 

1                 3                             asdasdwdfef
2                 3                             rgrgtggt
3                 3                             weef
```

Now, how do we get those values:

I chose to use two functions:

The names are related to the `mysql` function ['FIND_IN_SET'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

1) The `COUNT_IN_SET` function: returns the count of `character delimited items` in the column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `COUNT_IN_SET`(haystack VARCHAR(1024), 
                               delim CHAR(1)
                               ) RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
      RETURN CHAR_LENGTH(haystack) - CHAR_LENGTH( REPLACE(haystack, delim, '')) + 1;
END$$
```

2) The `VALUE_IN_SET` function: treats the `delimited list` as a `one based array` and returns the value at the  given 'index'.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `VALUE_IN_SET`(haystack VARCHAR(1024), 
                               delim CHAR(1), 
                               which INTEGER
                               ) RETURNS VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
BEGIN
      RETURN  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(haystack, delim, which),
                     delim,
                     -1);
END$$
```

The intereseries table - see (Tally tables)

```
CREATE TABLE `integerseries` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=500 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

/*Data for the table `integerseries` */

insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (1);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (2);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (3);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (4);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (5);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (6);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (7);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (8);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (9);
insert  into `integerseries`(`id`) values (10);
```

Comment: thanx for your post, but i got the answer.

Comment: @user3441151, I am pleased you got an answer you are happy with.

Comment: Thank you for the bonus. It is appreciated.