# MySQL explode comma separated string in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have table :

```
id | name    
1  | a,b,c    
2  | b
```

in another table i want like this :

```
id | parent | name    
1  |   1    | a   
2  |   1    | b   
3  |   1    | c   
4  |   2    | b
```

Please help me how to get it done in MySQL

Comment: First of all, you need to splt that string. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928599/equivalent-of-explode-to-work-with-strings-in-mysql

Comment: So do you want to insert first table's data into second table ?

Comment: yes @AliKhanusiya i want to insert in 2nd table

Comment: Is it Ok if I will provide solution using PHP + MySQL ?

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37230297/3184785 - generate rows from a delimited string.

Comment: Hopefully this endeavor is to correct and never use again CSV data in a column. Lord let's hope so.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya no, actually i know how to do it with PHP, but i need it by MySQL, i think Stored Procedure will help in this