# Count distinct letters in a string in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string column in Biquery like:

```sql
select 'A' 
union all (select 'ab')
union all (select 'abc')
union all (select 'aa')
union all (select 'aab')
```

I would like to count the number of distinct characters in every row of the column, in this case the results would be:

```
1
2
3
1
2
```

Can this be done in BigQuery? How?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count number of unique characters in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967280/count-number-of-unique-characters-in-a-string)

Comment: Not really, doesn't really solve the problem in a simple way, and it's not BigQuery, it's SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this (assuming you don't want to differentiate between uppercase and lowercase)...

```
WITH data AS (select 'A' AS `val`
              union all (select 'ab')
              union all (select 'abc')
              union all (select 'aa')
              union all (select 'aab'))
SELECT `val`, 26 - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '['||LOWER(`val`)||']', ''))
FROM `data`;
```

Comment: if you need to differentiate between uppercase and lowercase or 0-9, just update the source regex string and the length of this string.
 SELECT `val`, 52- LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '['||`val`||']', ''))

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to use the [`SPLIT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) to convert your string to an array and [`UNNEST`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator)  to convert the resulting array to a table. You may then use `COUNT` and `DISTINCT` to determine the number of unique characters as shown below:

```sql
with my_data AS (
   select 'A' as col
union all (select 'ab')
union all (select 'abc')
union all (select 'aa')
union all (select 'aab')
)

select col, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT element FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(col,'')) as element
)) n from my_data;
```

or simply

```sql
WITH my_data AS (
   SELECT 'A' as col UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'ab'       UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'abc'      UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'aa'       UNION ALL 
   SELECT 'aab'
)
SELECT 
    col, 
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT element) 
        FROM 
            UNNEST(SPLIT(col,'')) as element
    ) cnt 
FROM 
    my_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like previous but using `COUNT` with `DISTINCT`

```
with my_data AS (
select 'A' as col
union all (select 'ab')
union all (select 'abc')
union all (select 'aa')
union all (select 'aab')
)

select col, COUNT(DISTINCT element) FROM 
my_data,UNNEST(SPLIT(col,'')) as element
GROUP BY col
```

Answer (score 1):

If the data is not quite huge, I would rather go with the [user-defined functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) to ease up the string manipulation across different columns

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  get_unique_char_count(x STRING)
  RETURNS INT64
  LANGUAGE js AS r"""
    str_split = new Set(x.split(""));
    return str_split.size;
  """;
WITH
  result AS (
  SELECT
    'A' AS val
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      'ab')
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      'abc')
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      'aa')
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      'aab') )
SELECT
  val,
  get_unique_char_count(val) unique_char_count
FROM
  result
```

RESULT:

[image]