# mysql remove letters from string

Tags: mysql

I want remove letters from my string like this:

```
select CAST(dstring as number), * from myTable
```

dstring can be M-St2, DE2, M12,

result should be 2, 2, 12

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: @NickSavenia nope, that's not a duplicate, since in that question all numbers are in the front and a single number is returned.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the number in column. For example 'John12' delete '12' from column then return 'John', then replace 'John'. You can get '12'.

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(dstring, REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE (
    REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(dstring ,'0','')
    ,'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'5',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9',''), '')
FROM myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nailed it.... this will remove a-z and A-Z leaving all other characters behind...

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_field = REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(some_field,'a','') ,'b','') ,'c','') ,'d','') ,'e','') ,'f','') ,'g','') ,'h','') ,'i','') ,'j','') ,'k','') ,'l','') ,'m','') ,'n','') ,'o','') ,'p','') ,'q','') ,'r','') ,'s','') ,'t','') ,'u','') ,'v','') ,'w','') ,'x','') ,'y','') ,'z','') ,'A','') ,'B','') ,'C','') ,'D','') ,'E','') ,'F','') ,'G','') ,'H','') ,'I','') ,'J','') ,'K','') ,'L','') ,'M','') ,'N','') ,'O','') ,'P','') ,'Q','') ,'R','') ,'S','') ,'T','') ,'U','') ,'V','') ,'W','') ,'X','') ,'Y','') ,'Z','');
```

And here's my PHP to generate that (add any other characters you need in the $to_remove string:

```
$to_remove = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$removals = str_split($to_remove,1);
$stmt = "some_field";
foreach($removals as $x) {
    $stmt = " REPLACE(".$stmt.",'".$x."','') ";
}
$stmt = "update some_table set some_field = ".$stmt." ";
echo($stmt);
```

Answer (score -3):

Try to do this code,it may helpfull to you.

dstring can be M-St2, DE2, M12,

result should be 2, 2, 12

only display numeric value.

SELECT NumericOnly(dstring) as number from myTable

Comment: I don't think mysql has such a function. Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: actually you want to remove letters from the data..is it

Comment: Yes , but how does your solution help then NumericOnly is not a mysql function (that I can find)?

Comment: please refer this link

Comment: https://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/

Comment: pleasen refer this link,may be it will help https://venerableagents.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/mysql-numeric-functions/

Comment: This is not a standard mysql function, so, you should reference the website **and** the code (yes, you must copy the code) in your answer. Without these, your answer is meaningless.