# How to print a contact number leaving country code and '-','/' and print the rest of contact number using regular expressions in sql?

Tags: sql

I would like to print only contact number leaving country code aside using regular expressions.
Let us assume a table with 2 contacts

```
PHONENO
-----------
+89-8646538468
+0222-4684653453465
```

EXPECTING OUTPUT:

```
PHONENO
----------------
8646538468
4684653453465
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: SELECT Phoneno, SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(Phoneno,'-',''),5)
 FROM Phone_no;

Comment: dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql

Comment: I want it to happen using regular expression

Comment: @user8795734 MySQL has no built in support for regex replacement/extraction.  You will need to either use the base string functions, or use/create a UDF.

Comment: Yayyyyy!! Got that guys using regular expressions. I am unable to find an answer button here. can I comment

Comment: SELECT Phoneno ,SUBSTR(Phoneno,REGEXP_INSTR(Phoneno,'-')+1) FROM Phone_no;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy using MySQL's `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function:

```
SELECT
    PHONENO AS full_number,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(PHONENO, '-', -1) AS short_number
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Can you please help me write a code with regular expression as well.

Comment: I guess you missed my comment above.  You **can't** extract using regex in MySQL, because there is no such function.

Comment: Yayy!! Thanks guys. Got that using regular expressions only.Here is the code followed :-                                                                                  
SELECT Phoneno ,SUBSTR(Phoneno,REGEXP_INSTR(Phoneno,'-')+1) FROM Phone_no;

Comment: can you help me in making my question valid. I am new here, so please.

Comment: please upvote my question bro

Comment: I upvoted a long time ago already.

Comment: Please post my comment as answer bro! I am unable to post an answer