# mysql concat_ws with the result of a custom function prevents like '%str%' from working

Tags: mysql, function, sql-like, concat-ws

So I have the following sql that works:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('',`brand`,`pattern`,`product_code`,`size`,`normal_price`,`sale_price`,`text_special`,`load_index`,`speed_index`,`id`) `all_columns` FROM baz_tyres
    HAVING (`all_columns`  LIKE '%con%')
    ORDER BY brand asc
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

This works fine returning any record that contains the search string in any column such as "ContinentalContiCrossContactÂ® LX21549340225/65R17."

But then I also wanted to be able to match just the numerical value from size so I added the custom function I wound here:
[How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `ExtractNumber`(in_string VARCHAR(50)) 
RETURNS INT
NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE ctrNumber VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE finNumber VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE sChar VARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE inti INTEGER DEFAULT 1;

    IF LENGTH(in_string) > 0 THEN
        WHILE(inti <= LENGTH(in_string)) DO
            SET sChar = SUBSTRING(in_string, inti, 1);
            SET ctrNumber = FIND_IN_SET(sChar, '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9'); 
            IF ctrNumber > 0 THEN
                SET finNumber = CONCAT(finNumber, sChar);
            END IF;
            SET inti = inti + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN CAST(finNumber AS UNSIGNED);
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now that I have this function I also want to concat the resulting number and use it for the search.

So I added ExtractNumber(`size`) into the congat

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('',ExtractNumber(`size`),`brand`,`pattern`,`product_code`,`size`,`normal_price`,`sale_price`,`text_special`,`load_index`,`speed_index`,`id`) `all_columns` FROM baz_tyres
HAVING (`all_columns`  LIKE '%con%')
ORDER BY brand asc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

When the function is involved the like search fails to find any matches. However if I change the havving to a where condition checking for a specific brand name...

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('',ExtractNumber(`size`),`brand`,`pattern`,`product_code`,`size`,`normal_price`,`sale_price`,`text_special`,`load_index`,`speed_index`,`id`) `all_columns` FROM baz_tyres
WHERE (`brand`  LIKE '%con%')
ORDER BY brand asc
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Then I can see that indeed the concat with the function inside does actually work returning "2147483647ContinentalVancoFourSeason 20473361205/7...." but performing a like on this resulting string doesn't match when it should.

Some columns have special chars and I have tried casting the function result to utf8 and it had no effect.

Any ideas why I cant do a like on this concat string?

UPDATE:
It's working now..
I had to put the conversion inside the iterator function itself.

```
RETURN CAST(finNumber AS CHAR);
```

For some reason convert or cast with the function inside would produce the correct result but still wouldn't allow a like comparison to match afterwards.

So now the following query

```
SELECT *,CONCAT_WS('',ExtractNumber_CHAR(`size`),`brand`,`pattern`,`product_code`,`size`,`normal_price`,`sale_price`,`text_special`,`load_index`,`speed_index`,`id`) `all_columns` 
FROM `baz_tyres` 
HAVING (`all_columns` LIKE '%nat%' )
ORDER BY `brand`  DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Produces the desired result however a NEW problem has now appeared that is really strange..

If I do the exact same query but order by ASC instead of DESC then I get 0 results.

Really strange that order affects weather any results are returned. If the extract number function is removed ordering either way returns results.

When I put the function back in I can only get results when order by desc.

Can anyone tell me why this odd behavior would occur?

Answer (score 0):

Snytax of using having clause is this
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE condition
GROUP BY column_name(s)
HAVING condition
ORDER BY 
Having is used with aggregated function after using group by 
Try to change query by using group by else use where instead having

Comment: Cant use where on a concat thats why I was using having since the `all_columns` feild doesn't exist until after the select statement is processed hence, why I was using having. Having works fine when the function isnt part of the concat. And not sure how I can add group by into this because I want individual results. Can I group by nothing somehow to test is having works after groupby?