# How to search maximum id with constant value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an id column in table with following data:

```
K1
K2
K3
....
876
765
887
K12
K13
```

I want to find the max id with constant 'K'
I have used following syntax

```
Select max(id) from table where id like 'k%'
```

The end result is K9
How can I get the accurate result which is k13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: You could try using `SUBSTRING()` to remove the k before checking the max, but that might require using a sub-select.  It would be helpful to know more about the table structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You where close, try:

```
Select CONCAT('K', MAX(CAST(REPLACE(id, 'K', '') AS UNSIGNED))) as maximum 
from table 
where id like 'K%'
```

Comment: Added `CAST..  AS UNSIGNED` to your query; it is required to treat the modified string as integer value for comparison and determining MAX() value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

1. Replace `K` with Empty String.
2. Convert `String` to `Number`.
3. Take `MAX` from the result.
4. Finally append `K` with `MAX` value.

   SELECT CONCAT('K', MAX(CAST(REPLACE(id, 'K', '') AS UNSIGNED))) as max
   FROM table
   WHERE id LIKE 'K%';

Comment: That's the good one (Last point). Just a suggestion: Write your code in code blocks so the answer would be easily readable!!!