# In MySQL how to get numbers after a specific word

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with descriptions of products.  Within those descriptions are product dimensions, though not all in the same position.

How can I pull out just the widths in numbers from the following example data
Description

- Table Width (cm) 100
- Bed, Width: 90cm
- Office Desk Width - 200 cm.  Color - Black
- Couch with Width of 500 cm
- Chair - width(50.5cm)

Have used substring_index function to get the text between 'width' and 'cm', but haven't been able to grab then just the numbers within that. (and that doesn't work for record 1 above

```sql
SELECT description, substring_index(substring_index(description, 'width', -1),'cm', 1)
FROM productlisting
```

Expected output:

- 100
- 90
- 200
- 500
- 50.5

Actual

- 
- : 90
- - 200
- of 500
- (50.5

Comment: With no consistency of input, this will be a struggle. You will probably need to parse the data several times to deal with every situation

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql/37269038#37269038

Comment: Never more than one number?

Comment: Is it too late to redesign the database to be more user friendly?

Comment: use regex_replace() just like select regex_replace(description,'[^0-9]','')

Comment: @Mark McP is there only 1 number in the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use `regexp_replace()` to get the first number after "Width"

```
select regexp_replace(d, '.*Width[^0-9]*', '') + 0
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I should have mentioned however we are still on MySQL 5.7. So I'm out of luck with this one.

Another reason here to upgrade but theres some hesitation from those responsible for the db.

Comment: Hi again Gordon.  Managed to dump the table into an 8.0 DB.
I'm using MySQL Workbench to run the query, however unless my limit is set very low (<100 rows) it returns :
Error Code: 3699. Timeout exceeded in regular expression match.

The field I'm searching in is a longtext field, with A full text index.  
The table has 190K rows in total

Comment: @MarkMcP . . . I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: In MySQL workbench I run:
select regexp_replace(description, '.*Width[^0-9]*', '') from productlist + 0

The system then throws up message:
Error Code: 3699. Timeout exceeded in regular expression match. 0.204 sec

Answer (score 1):

If there is only 1 number in the description, just like your sample data, you can use [`Mysql string functions`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) to get that number like this:

```
select
  p.description,
  substr(p.description, min(locate(d.digit, p.description))) + 0 number
from (
  select 0 digit union all select 1 union all
  select 2 union all select 3 union all
  select 4 union all select 5 union all
  select 6 union all select 7 union all
  select 8 union all select 9 
) d inner join productlisting p
on p.description like concat('%', d.digit, '%')
group by p.description
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4CuUhJzyjMeBpRhzL38J3T/4).
Results:

```
|description                                | number |
| ----------------------------------------- | ------ |
| Bed, Width: 90cm                          | 90     |
| Chair - width(50.5cm)                     | 50.5   |
| Couch with Width of 500 cm                | 500    |
| Office Desk Width - 200 cm. Color - Black | 200    |
| Table Width (cm) 100                      | 100    |
```

Comment: Thanks forpas
unfortunately though my sample data was simplified.  Actual data can have more than 1 number, eg:  
- "Width 680mm  Height 920mm  Weight 23Kg  Specifications for the 5Ft Option    Length 1460mm "

Comment: Better change your design. Sql code cannot spot a number anywhere in the description among other numbers when there is no pattern to search for.

Comment: Wish it was that simple.  The data is coming from other sources and all over the place. We will look into more advanced solutions.  cheers