# Replacing multiple values in a string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

[image]

I have a column in my table which has below values and I need the o/p in the following format: 
(Example: `S-S-661679`. It should in the format `S-######`).

The third o/p below is the required o/p in the correct format.

```
Column Value are like:
'S-S-652235'
'S-xjq113465'
**'S-652235'**
'-641408'
```

I am using MySQL to query this data from the table. Few columns have the correct value but there are alphabets also and the final o/p should have just S-######. I was thinking of using Regular Expression but could not figure out how to use that in SELECT Clause, all the examples I have seen, I see that it can only be used in WHERE Clause.

I am using below code:
`**CONCAT('S-', REPLACE(REPLACE(`seminar_id`, ',', ''), 's', ''))**` in the select clause, but it is replicating the `'S-'` which is already present in some columns. I am trying to figure out how to replace multiple `'S-'` and also the alphabetical characters from the values in the columns.

(Example: `S-S-661679`. It should in the format `S-######`).

The third o/p below is the required o/p in the correct format and the highlighted in the image attached is the correct format.

```
Column Value are like:
'S-S-652235'
'S-xjq113465'
**'S-652235'**
'-641408'
```

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you want to select all rows, but reformat the value to match the format of `S-652235`? So `S-S-652235` would become `S-652235`, `S-xjq113465` would become `S-113465`, `S-652235` would be returned as-is, and `-641408` would become `S-641408`?

Comment: Yes @WOUNDEDStevenJones, this is exactly how I am looking for the data to be!

Comment: getting formats 1, 3, and 4 to just `######` and then prepending `S-` seems to be trivial (and it looks like you're basically there: `REPLACE(REPLACE(val, 'S-', ''), '-', '')`). So in order to fix format #2 check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql. Then you'd end up with a digits-only string, and similarly you can just prepend `S-` and you have everything in the same format.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  8.0 has `REGEXP_REPLACE()`, which makes it easy.