# I have a double relation of the id of one table to another table and I need to build a relation with the same id in another table twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

| id | subOperation |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 |
| 2 | test2 |
| 3 | test3 |
| 4 | test1,test2 |
| 5 | test1,test3 |

I need help, to make a query which gives me the following result

| id | idSubOperation | idElement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 5 | 3 |

When I have one ","
I need to assemble the id
How can I do it?

**The idElement of the id is also obtained, but taking into account the name of the suboperation.And it can be more than one ,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are at most two elements in the `subOperation` (as in your example), you can use `union all` to bring together the different components of the final result set:

```
select row_number() over (order by id_suboperation, id_element) as id, tt.*
from ((select id as id_suboperation, id as id_element
       from t
       where t.subOperation not like '%,%'
      ) union all
      (select t.id, tsub.id
       from t join
            t tsub
            on substring_index(t.subOperation, ',', 1) = tsub.subOperation
       where t.subOperation like '%,%'
      ) union all
      (select t.id, tsub.id
       from t join
            t tsub
            on substring_index(t.subOperation, ',', -1) = tsub.subOperation
       where t.subOperation like '%,%'
      )
     ) tt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e2ce8735916951c70a6ede02a595bc7) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that this can pretty easily be extended to longer lists of values, but only two seem necessary for this question.

EDIT:

The only issue in MySQL 5.6 is assigning the row number.  You can use:

```
set @rn = 0;

select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, tt.*
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you very much, in MySQL 8.0 it works correctly. But it gives problems in MySQL 5.6

Any solution, what can you recommend me?

Comment: In version 5.6 
gives the error of:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by id_suboperation, id_element) as id, tt.*
from ((select id as id_subope' at line 1"

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this platform, I thought I could accept more than one answer. As his was the last one, it was the one that stayed @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

```sql
create table tab1 as
    select 1 as id, 'test1' as subOperation union all
    select 2 as id, 'test2' as subOperation union all
    select 3 as id, 'test3' as subOperation union all
    select 4 as id, 'test1,test2' as subOperation union all
    select 5 as id, 'test1,test3' union all
    select 6 as id, 'test1,test3,test2';

select * from tab1;

with recursive t1(id, suboperation, lv) as (
select t0.id, t0.suboperation, 1 level from tab1 t0
 union all
select t2.id, t2.suboperation, t1.lv + 1 from tab1 t2, t1
 where t2.id = t1.id
   and t1.lv <= length(t1.suboperation) - length(replace(t2.suboperation, ',', ''))
), 
tab2 as (
select row_number() over(order by t1.id) id,
       t1.id idSubOperation,
       regexp_substr(t1.suboperation, '[^,]+', 1, row_number() over(partition by t1.id)) suboperation
  from t1
)
select t1.*,
       t2.id idElement
  from tab2 t1,
       (select * from tab1 t1 where t1.subOperation not regexp ',') t2
 where t1.suboperation = t2.suboperation
 order by t1.id
;
```

mysql5.6 ,A little complicated, but can be simplified with a custom function

```sql
#drop FUNCTION split_substr;
CREATE FUNCTION split_substr(p_src varchar(2000), p_split VARCHAR(200), p_num int)
    RETURNS varchar(2000) 
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    declare f_res VARCHAR(2000);
    while p_num > 0 do
        select case when instr(p_src, p_split) = 0 and length(p_src) > 0 then p_src else
                 substr(p_src, 1, instr(p_src, p_split) - length(p_split))
               end,
               substr(p_src, case when instr(p_src, p_split) = 0 then length(p_src) + 1 else
                                instr(p_src, p_split) + length(p_split)
                             end)
          into f_res, p_src;
        set p_num = p_num - 1;
    end while;
    RETURN f_res;
end;

select t1.*,
       t2.id,
       @rownum:=@rownum+1
  from (
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 1) name from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 2) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 3) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 4) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 5) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 6) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 7) from tab1 t1 union all
select t1.id, t1.subOperation, split_substr(t1.subOperation, ',', 8) from tab1 t1 
) t1,
  (select * from tab1 t1 where t1.subOperation not regexp ',') t2,
  (select @rownum:=0) t3
 where t1.name = t2.subOperation
   and length(t1.name) > 0
 order by t1.id
;
```

Comment: In MySQL 8.0 it works correctly. Thanks!
But in mysql 5.6 it gives me error in  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'recursive t1(id, suboperation, lv) as (
select t0.id, t0.suboperation, 1 level f' at line 1"
I'm sorry, I think I forgot to put the version, any recommendation that you can give me

Answer (score 0):

Also possible using [PREPARED STATEMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

```
SET @sql := NULL;
  
SET @sql := (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_suboperation, 
                     id_element) AS id, 
                     id_suboperation, id_element 
                FROM (',GROUP_CONCAT(qv SEPARATOR ' union all '),' ) sq 
                GROUP BY id_suboperation, id_element 
                ORDER BY id_suboperation, id_element;')
          FROM
(SELECT CONCAT("SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',",idx,"),',',-1) AS id_element
FROM mytable") qv FROM mytable a CROSS JOIN
(WITH RECURSIVE wordCount AS (
SELECT 1 IDX, 
       (LENGTH(subOperation)-LENGTH(REPLACE(subOperation,',','')))+1 AS MAXCOUNT 
  FROM mytable UNION ALL
SELECT IDX+1, MAXCOUNT FROM wordCount WHERE IDX+1 <= MAXCOUNT)
SELECT IDX FROM wordCount
GROUP BY IDX) b
GROUP BY qv) c);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

At least with new data being added, you don't need to change the statement.

P/S: I personally like [@nayi224's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68402619/10910692) though.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a1f8142fdc9a66b72a455e3451029bf

**Update:**

For older MySQL version that don't support `WITH` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SET @sql := NULL;
  
SET @sql := (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT (@rownum := @rownum+1) AS Rownum, 
                     id_suboperation, id_element 
              FROM 
                 (SELECT * 
              FROM (',GROUP_CONCAT(qv SEPARATOR ' union all '),' ) sq 
                  GROUP BY id_suboperation, id_element) vr 
               CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) rn 
            ORDER BY id_suboperation, id_element;')
            FROM
           (SELECT CONCAT("SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                   SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                       REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',",idx,"),',',-1) AS 
              id_element
             FROM mytable") qv FROM mytable a CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 IDX UNION 
 SELECT 2 UNION 
 SELECT 3 UNION 
 SELECT 4) b
GROUP BY qv) c);

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

This will return `@sql` as following:

```
SELECT (@rownum := @rownum+1) AS Rownum, id_suboperation, id_element 
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',1),',',-1) AS id_element
FROM mytable union all SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',2),',',-1) AS id_element
FROM mytable union all SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',3),',',-1) AS id_element
FROM mytable union all SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
              REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',4),',',-1) AS id_element
FROM mytable ) sq 
GROUP BY id_suboperation, id_element) vr 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) rn 
ORDER BY id_suboperation, id_element;
```

As for your question *"And also, what happens when all the words don't start with test?"* , if the string value is consistent, then you can just replace `test` with a different word from this part:

```
....
REPLACE(subOperation,'test',''),',',",idx,"),',',-1) AS id_element
                      ^^^^
                      here
....
```

If the string parts are not consistent but the numerical value is always at the end, you may try using `REVERSE()` with `CAST` or just `REVERSE(REVERSE(string)+0)`. The conversion from string to numbers only I referred from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37269038/10910692) . So, the query for setting `@sql` might be something like this at the end:

```
SET @sql :=  (SELECT CONCAT('SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id_suboperation, 
                     id_element) AS id, 
                     id_suboperation, id_element 
                FROM (',GROUP_CONCAT(qv SEPARATOR ' union all '),' ) sq 
                GROUP BY id_suboperation, id_element 
                ORDER BY id_suboperation, id_element;')
          FROM
(SELECT CONCAT("SELECT id AS id_suboperation, 
      REVERSE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(subOperation,',',",idx,"),',',-1))+0) AS id_element
FROM mytable") qv FROM mytable a CROSS JOIN
(SELECT 1 IDX UNION 
 SELECT 2 UNION 
 SELECT 3 UNION 
 SELECT 4) b
GROUP BY qv) c);
```

The `REVERSE()` function is repeated because if the string value is like this `test53`, the first reverse will make it as `35tset`. Then after using `CAST()` or `+0` on it, the number value will become `35` instead of `53` from the original string value. Therefore, to get the correct number from the original string, it has to be reversed again.

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f5177a3c164971a03faa8619e4050951)

Comment: It works perfect on MySQL 8.0, but I am using version 5.6

Comment: And it does not give me results, but thank you very much in MySQL 8.0 it works correctly

Comment: And also, what happens when all the words don't start with test?.I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain it well

Comment: Yes, you are correct. ROW_NUMBER() and WITH RECURSIVE doesn't work in v5.6 but prepared statement should. Please check my edit for an option for v5.6.