# MySQL Virtual Column Wrong Values

Tags: mysql, laravel, generated-columns

i really loves mysql virtual generated columns but am having a small issue with it am trying to make a virtual column from a varchar column where i extract the number as the following.

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE reservations ADD number_vc  BIGINT AS (REVERSE(REVERSE(number) << 0)) ');
```

my issue is in this part `REVERSE(REVERSE(number) << 0))`

as if you tried now to run this part of sql in any sql editor as the following

```
SELECT REVERSE(REVERSE("A100") << 0)
```

it will generate the following

[image]

**What Am Trying To Achieve **

if the string was A100 after reverse i need 100 also the schema of the varchar not always one character it may be like this
A100 , AA100 , AB100

**Edit 2 :Am Afraid i did go production a week a go and here is the result **

[image]

Comment: No. ```REVERSE("A100") << 0``` produces "1" and ```REVERSE(1)``` produces 1. Nothing wrong here. You should say what you're trying to achieve and give sample datas so we understand better

Comment: If you want to trim the leading "A" you can use SUBSTR: `SELECT SUBSTR("A100", 2);`

Comment: IF it's always using that format and always using only one letter than yes, what Vadim said should be enough
EDIT: OK not always one letter then that's different

Comment: @VadimSirbu no it is not always one character it may be 2 like A100 , AA100 , AB100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Refresh the page to see my answer

Answer (score 0):

With mySQL8+ you can do this :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('A100', '\D', '');
```

It's basically replacing non digits characters with nothing using a regexp.

Comment: am afraid i cant use Mysql8 version as we have 5.7.23 so this function will be unavailable

Comment: Ok, then at this point you have to write a function that removes all non digits character. You'll find plenty online, some very efficient even.