# Truncated incorrect INTEGER value (IN FUNCTION ONLY)

Tags: mysql

I've looked through several other possible solutions here on stack overflow but I'm still stuck. The following code is just a simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

Running

```
select CONVERT( '1510SBrownlee' , SIGNED INTEGER);
```

works perfeclty fine. It returns 1510 as expected.

The issue arises when the same code is placed in a function. (Again, please note that this is not my actual function, I'm using the following as a simple example... In my actual function, I'm passing a parameter).

After creating

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION testing_function() RETURNS varchar(255) 
BEGIN
DECLARE testt varchar(255);

SET testt = CONVERT( '1510SBrownlee' , SIGNED INTEGER);
RETURN testt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error when I run `select testing_function();`

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: '1510SBrownlee'

Why is this working when I run it directly as opposed to when in a function? Is there a way to make that work in the function? I've also tried CAST as SIGNED as opposed to CONVERT. Same issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for sharing this! I used the idea behind that and added a 0 at the end of the string before converting it. That works perfectly. ```CONVERT(concat( '1510SBrownlee', '0') , SIGNED INTEGER);```

Comment: For that method, I'd be concerned with what would happen if the string had no alpha characters after the numeric characters.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good point. For the purpose of my project, it will always have an alpha character, but that's good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it works when I convert to `DECIMAL`. I don't know why but hey, it works. I'll take other answers though!!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE  FUNCTION testing_function() RETURNS varchar(255) 
BEGIN
DECLARE testt varchar(255);

SET testt = CONVERT( '1510SBrownlee' , DECIMAL);
RETURN testt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```