# MySQL extract first 4 digits

Tags: mysql

I want to run a query in mysql which will return the record where the first 4 digits are '0123' or '0798' from the following column:

| Number |
| --- |
| 0123 427 6465 |
| 0123 1451 |
| 01 23 46 47 |
| 0123 945675 |
| 07984 473456 |
| 0845 46 47 |
| (012377) 5258 |
| 0800 586931 |
| 012 3668 6098 |
| 0 1238592371 |

I want the query to return all records where '0123' or '0798' are the first 4 numeric characters regardless of if there are other characters before or in between. E.g. I would want record 7 returned even though '0123' is in brackets. And I would want record 10 returned even though it is written as '0 123' i.e. there is a space in between.

Is regex relevant here? If so, what would the regex expression be?

Comment: `select left(Number,4) from ......` or `select substring(Number,4) from ......` (see [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) or [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring))

Comment: Please share more info ... ("the records are not uniform")

Comment: You could [TRIM](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-trim/) any leading '(', [REPLACE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-string-replace-function.aspx) the spaces with nothing, and check the [LEFT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-function/) four characters.

Comment: SQL isn't good at this sort of thing , maybe use a language which is good with arrays eg python

Comment: go for a regular expression everyone scares lol

Comment: below theres a query using regex :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `LEFT` and `REPLACE`.
`REPLACE` will strip out any unwanted brackets and whitespaces, and `LEFT` will select the first four characters, starting from left, of the newly formatted value which will be used in the `WHERE` clause selecting for values `IN` `'0123', '0798'`.

```
SELECT `number` FROM Numbers WHERE LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(`number`, '(', ''), ')', ''), ' ', ''), 4) IN ('0123', '0798')
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c77c2c3fc770676d896dfa5bb596ada).

**Result:**

| Number |
| --- |
| 0123 427 6465 |
| 0123 1451 |
| 01 23 46 47 |
| 0123 945675 |
| 07984 473456 |
| (012377) 5258 |
| 012 3668 6098 |
| 0 1238592371 |

Also, it's worth noting, `number` is a [Reserved Word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#:%7E:text=in%208.0.2%20(nonreserved)-,NUMBER,-NUMERIC%20(R)) in MySQL. I used backticks ` to escape it, however, it is advised that you do not use reserved words in your naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function to remove all others characters other than number and get first four using the below query,

```
SELECT LEFT(REGEXP_REPLACE(Number, '[^0-9]+', ''), 4) as 4digitonly FROM Numbers a;
```

Please refer [How to get only Digits from String in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37268248/how-to-get-only-digits-from-string-in-mysql)

Comment: this is not the response to the answer, it is returning 10 rows which means all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is better than regex, yes they make us think even think recursivelly :)
Here is the query(of course it can be refactored N times):

```
SELECT n.number FROM Numbers n WHERE n.number REGEXP '^.*(0[ \t\r\n]*1[ \t\r\n]*2[ \t\r\n]*3).*|^.*(0[ \t\r\n]*7[ \t\r\n]*9[ \t\r\n]*8).*$'
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e442d77e1ef038326531285127913b71)