# In SQL, have a string but I need two different columns

Tags: oracle

I have a string like 'A1B2C3D4' in one table column, but I need numbers and characters individually in two different columns in the same table.

The same table contains another columns like one is for characters and another one is for numbers

Answer (score 2):

A simple option is to remove what you don't want using regular expressions:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'A1B2C3D4' from dual)
  3  select regexp_replace(col, '[[:digit:]]') letters,
  4         regexp_replace(col, '[[:alpha:]]') numbers
  5  from test;

LETTERS    NUMBERS
---------- ----------
ABCD       1234

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

[reference comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68580907/20559053)

It can be acieve using query like,

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C3D4',"[^0-9]+","") as numbers, REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C3D4',"[0-9]+","") as texts
```

For Oracle SQL

```sql
select REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C3D4','[^0-9]+','') as numbers, REGEXP_REPLACE('A1B2C3D4','[0-9]+','') as texts from dual;
```

Comment: Not exactly; link you posted is related to **MySQL**; this question is about Oracle and your code won't work. It *would* if you used single instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple string functions are often much faster than regular expressions.

Assuming that your string only contains letters and/or numbers then you can solve this using `TRANSLATE` to remove either the numbers (to leave only the letters) or the letters (to leave only the numbers):

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(column_name, 'A1234567890', 'A') AS letters,
       TRANSLATE(column_name, '0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', '0') AS numbers
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (column_name) AS
SELECT 'A1B2C3D4' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| LETTERS | NUMBERS |
| --- | --- |
| ABCD | 1234 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6CX3Uh9m)

Comment: That wouldn't work properly in some other languages (different from English); for example, German umlauts (ö) or certain Slavic (č) characters would end in both *letters* and *numbers*.

Comment: @Littlefoot If you have other characters than A-Z, 0-9 then modify the list of characters in the second argument to include the appropriate characters from your alphabet as either numbers to remove or letters to remove (and if you have characters that should be in both letters and numbers then don't remove them from either).