# how to count the matched keywords using select in mysql codeigniter php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, select

how to count the matched keywords using select in mysql codeigniter php? here is my table

Ex. assuming that the search keywords are yes, test

```
messages table

id | title     | msg               |date
---+-----------+-------------------+-------------+--      
1  |  test1    |  yes              | 2016-06-01 // 2 match keywords
2  |  yes1     |  no               | 2016-06-02 // 1 match keywords   
3  |  test2    |  no               | 2016-06-03 // 1 match keywords
4  |  yes2     |  yes yes yes      | 2016-06-04 // 4 match keywords
5  |  yesyes3  |  yes yes yes yes  | 2016-06-05 // 6 match keywords
```

now need to display it with count_match column

```
id | title     | msg               |date        |count_match    
---+-----------+-------------------+------------+-------------------    
1  |  test1    |  yes              | 2016-06-01 | 2
2  |  yes1     |  no               | 2016-06-02 | 1  
3  |  test2    |  no               | 2016-06-03 | 1
4  |  yes2     |  yes yes yes      | 2016-06-04 | 4
5  |  yesyes3  |  yes yes yes yes  | 2016-06-05 | 6
```

and for array it should displayed look like this

```
array (
    [0] => array (
        [id] => 5
        [title] => yesyes3
        [msg] => yes yes yes yes
        [date] => 2016-06-05
        [match] => 6
    )
    [1] => array (
        [id] => 4
        [title] => yes2
        [msg] => yes yes yes
        [date] => 2016-06-04
        [match] => 4
    )
    [2] => array (
        [id] => 1
        [title] => test1
        [msg] => yes
        [date] => 2016-06-01
        [match] => 2
    )
    [3] => array (
        [id] => 3
        [title] => test2
        [msg] => no
        [date] => 2016-06-03
        [match] => 1
    )
    [4] => array (
        [id] => 2
        [title] => yes1
        [msg] => no
        [date] => 2016-06-02
        [match] => 1
    )
)
```

and currently my code in fetching for this is this

```
        $match = array('test','yes');
        $orderbyString1 = "";
        $orderbyString = "";
        $likestr = "";
        foreach($match AS $value)
        {
            $orderbyString .= "IF(m.title LIKE '%".$value."%' OR m.msg LIKE '%".$value."%',1,0)+";
            $likestr .= "m.title LIKE '%".$value."%' OR m.msg LIKE '%".$value."%' OR ";
        }
        $orderbyString = substr($orderbyString, 0, -1);
        $likestr = substr($likestr, 0, -4);
        $this->db->select('m.*, ('.$orderbyString.') as count_match');
        $this->db->from('messages m');
        $this->db->where($likestr." ORDER BY ".$orderbyString." DESC");

        $query = $this->db->get();

        $results = $query->result_array();
        print_r($results);exit;
```

Is there any way for the select to display the correct count_match using php codeigniter code? because currently it displays 1 and 2 under count_match.

Thanks!

Comment: it easier may be done by PHP - loop array and add  result of substr_count()

Comment: You can also use [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985) eg if you need caseless matching or word boundaries. See [demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/599468)

Comment: @bobblebubble thanks how about if the msg = testyestest and the title = yestest? the match_count should be 5

Comment: got it thanks to @splosh58 too I'll just do it in php though

Comment: @bobblebubble just post your answer below for me to mark it as the solution for this problem. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On php-side there are many options to count the keywords in your array. If you need additional functionality such as caseless matching or [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) how about using [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/5527985).

An idea with [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

> Returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

```
$pattern = '~(?:yes|test)~i';

foreach($arr AS $k => $v)
  $arr[$k]['match'] = preg_match_all($pattern, $v['title']." ".$v['msg']);
```

The pattern is simply an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) of the two keywords using a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group). After the closing [pattern delimiter](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `~` used the [`i` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for caseless matching. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mJ1xL1/2) is a nice place to test pattern.

[Here is a demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/599486)

If input is generic, use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape certain characters from it's special regex meaning.