# Find number of count of a word in column in each row

Tags: mysql

I have a table name 'answer' and where answer saved given by a user for a question.
User give multiple answer of a question.So answer save as string in 'answer' column.
My table look like this

```
id  userid   questionid  answer
 
1   2        5           red,blue,white,green

2   3        5           red,blue

3   5        5           red,white

4   6        5           blue,white,green

5   7        5           red,blue,white,green
```

I want to select those userid whose answer 3 value(blue,white,green) or more than 3(red,blue,white,green).
I have tried with `length` function but it not work.

Comment: this question has been answers multiple times http://stackoverflow.com/q/12344795/4323504

Comment: @The Flash This find a perticular word count

Comment: yes, you would put that in your where clause, okay i will add an answer for you

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link i provided on my comment ealier, you can accomplish what you want by doing this:

```
SELECT userid    
FROM AnswersTable 
WHERE ROUND (   
         (LENGTH(answer) - LENGTH( REPLACE ( answer, ",", "") ) ) / LENGTH(",")        
       ) > 2
```

Comment: one more question if in place of (,) if we use some ascii value so how can i do this?

Comment: what ASCII value you want to use?

Comment: 'Unit Separator' and hax value for  this '1F'

Comment: I think you should open another question, or try something like `'\x1F'` instead of `","` , remember 'Unit Separator' is unprintable, check here http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120205/discussion-between-ankit-and-the-flash).