# SQL Server parse a column's XML value into a table (for each row)

Tags: sql-server, xml

Sorry if the topic isn't very clear, but here is what I need to accomplish. I have a table like so:

```
 user_id   | friends
==============================
75          | <friend name="bob" /><friend name="joe" />
76          | <friend name="bill" /><friend name="bob" />
77          | <friend name="sam" /><friend name="gary" /><friend name="john" />
```

I need to get the number of friends (ie, number of XML nodes) for each user.
The resulting table should look like this:

```
 user_id   | number_of_friends
==============================
75         | 2
76         | 2
77         | 3
```

The following SQL can do it for one column at a time, but I'm not sure how to do it for all columns in one go.

```
DECLARE @x XML;

SELECT @x = pval 
FROM [mytable]
WHERE uid=75 AND pkey='roster';

SELECT COUNT(t.c.value('@name', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) AS number_of_friends
FROM @x.nodes('//friend') t(c);
```

This results in the table:

```
number_of_friends
=================
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is **SQL Server** you can use XQuery [count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/aggregate-functions-count) function:

```
SELECT  [user_id],
        friends.value('count(/friend)','integer') as number_of_friends
FROM YourTable
```

In **MySQL** - [ExtractValue()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue):

```
SELECT  `user_id`,
        ExtractValue(`friends`, 'count(/friend)')
FROM `YourTable`
```

Comment: I get this error: `Cannot find either column "friends" or the user-defined function or aggregate "friends.value", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: `friends` is XML datatype or varchar? If varchar - you need to use `CAST(friends as xml).value('count(/friend)','integer') as number_of_friends`

Comment: Thanks, casting the friends column to XML did the trick. it works now

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick: Remove (replace) what you are searching for and compare the difference in string length:

```
SELECT 
    user_id,    
    ROUND (
        (
            LENGTH(friends)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( friends, "<friend", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH("<friend")        
    ) AS count  
FROM friendtable
```

[Running fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/396b9/2)

[Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)

Comment: The `friends` column is an `ntext`, so the query was giving an error. Even after casting to `nvarchar(max)`, each column returns a value of 0. (Also, its Microsoft SQL Server, so the `length` function should be `len`, and the `round` function needs more than one parameter)

Comment: Ok, you tagged your question with mysql

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag. I gave you a +1 anyways though, thanks

Comment: Well, you *can* cut bread with a chain saw - but it's the wrong tool... This ought to be solved with XML's `XQuery`. Your approach would break in any case with another node starting with `<friend`. It would help to add a blank, but this is - uhm - the wrong tool :-)