# SQL Query beginner needing advice on filtering

Tags: sql, filtering

I'm trying to put together a query that can filter out a specific special character with the added condition that it will only give you the results if that special character only appears a certain number of times (in this case once).

My current query:

```
select k.name as 'GroupName'
  , k.Type as 'Factor'
From Kf as k
Join KfChildren as kc on k.ID = kc.id
Join Kf as k1 on kc.ChildID = k1.id
where k.name like ('ASX:%') --special character needed ":"
```

I'm looking for the query to bring back:

```
ASX:TRANSPORTATION
```

and not:

```
ASX:TSG:PSG:Rollers
```

Is this something that is doable or should I just try and figure something out?

Thanks in advance for anyone posting any responses to this :)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? what's your dbms

Comment: You may find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field

Comment: On SQL Server you could add something like `and charindex(':', k.name, 5) = 0`

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, @D-Shih: using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 as for sample data say the database contains: ASX:Transportation and ASX:TSG:PSG:Rollers I just want it to bring back the first one as it only has 1 colon in its name

Comment: @shawnt00: thanks shawn I think that has given me what I needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clause: starting with ASX and only one ':'

```
WHERE k.Name LIKE 'ASX:%'
AND NOT LIKE 'ASX:%:%'
```

Replace `ASX` with `%` if you need the wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE (upper(k.name) LIKE '%ASX:%'
  AND upper(k.name) NOT LIKE '%:%:%:')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it and it seems that I'm still getting results that have multiple ':' colons. need to somehow limit the results to those that just have one colon

Comment: That second pattern  allows for two colons but not three.

Answer (score 0):

Try This
            `WHERE k.name LIKE 'ASX[:]%' AND k.name NOT LIKE ‘%:%:%’`

Mark as solution if works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried this and it looks like I'm still getting results with multiple colons ':' need to somehow limit the results to those that just have one colon