# Explode and count in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column in table views: 165,75,44,458,458,42,45
This column contain user_ids who viewed a link.
I want to explode it by comma delimiter and count the ids

I tried this but it only counts all the character.

SQL:

```
SELECT LENGTH(views) FROM questions WHERE question_id=1;
```

This is the PHP version that I want to do in SQL

```
$viewers_ids  = "165,75,44,458,458,42,45";
$num_of_views = count(array_filter(explode(",", $viewers_ids)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can count the commas:

```
select 1 + length(views) - length(replace(views, ',', ''))
```

That said, you should fix your data structure.  You should not be storing multiple numeric ids in a string column -- that is just wrong in many ways.  You should be using a junction/association table.

Comment: Little corner case if your string is null, this solution will give you 1 instead of 0 ... I think :)

Comment: @LauDec . . . If the string is `NULL`, the value will be `NULL`.  The edge case is an empty string.  I'm not sure if that is an issue, but if it is, the `1` could be replaced with `(views is not null)`.

Comment: Yes sorry wanted to say empty string :) well as long as OP makes sure that he thought about this, we're good :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried the other way around i.e. to replace all characters other than `,`

```
     Select  
      Length(REGEXP_REPLACE
      (views,'[^\,]*',''))+1 from
         table
```

Comment: hummmm ...SELECT LOCATE('165,75,44,458,458,42,45',',',-1) +1 returns 1 on sqlfiddle. so i don't think it works

Comment: ohkay got it mysql din work as i thought coz its got complex syntax. ill update in a while

Answer (score 0):

My immediate reaction is that your table structure needs to change - I would expect there to be another table that joins question links and user_ids with a "visit_id" perhaps, and use visit_id as a foreign key in the views table.

My second reaction is that this is a perfect problem for a shell utility - maybe sed/,/ /g then wc -w, or a small awk script.

To do it in SQL, I might try to figure out how to count the number of commas, and add one. This answer gives you a function that will get you the number of commas by replacing them with "", then substracting the length from the length of the unmodified field: [Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)