# MySQL: Fill column 'a.total' from count of value 'a.name' in column 'b.content' of table 'b'

Tags: mysql, count

I'm trying to fill a column `a.total` with the number of occurrences of `a.name` in `b.content`.

```
       a                       b
+--------------+    +----------------------+
| name | total |    | content              |
+------+-------+    +----------------------+
| foo  |     3 |    | hello bar            |
| bar  |     4 |    | hola foofoo          |
+--------------+    | nihao foo, bye bar   |
                    | et bar se bar        |
                    +----------------------+
```

I tried the command below:

```
UPDATE a SET a.total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM b WHERE b.content LIKE CONCAT('%', a.name, '%') );
```

But I get this:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Rows matched: 4321  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0" with my command
```

What's wrong in this command ? And how can I also take into account all occurrences of `foo` and `bar` in a same `content` row ?

Comment: When I run your update, the result is `foo 2` and `bar 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field) shows how to count the occurrences of a substring in a column. You can then sum them to get the total across all rows.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.total = (
    SELECT SUM((CHAR_LENGTH(b.content) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(b.content, a.name, ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(a.name))
    FROM b
    WHERE b.content LIKE CONCAT('%', a.name, '%'))
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v15amZanQ95N9FnWV9R9Sw/2)

Comment: Many thanks! But for some reason, when I run this command, I get nothing unless aborting it : `ERROR 1317 (70100): Query execution was interrupted`. Is it because of mysql 8.0 version ? Or because my columns `a.name` and `b.content` contain characters which unicode is something like #E000 ?

Comment: Use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`, it does the right thing with multibyte characters.

Comment: still nothing, maybe I need to give it more execution time... (I have about ~5000 rows in `a` and ~100.000 in `b`) but I don't see the rows being filled and my cpu doesn't look overloaded.

Comment: Since this can't be indexed, this will be a very expensive query with so many rows. It has to calculate `SUM((CHAR_LENGTH(b.content) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(b.content, a.name, ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(a.name))` 500,000,000 times.

Comment: I just added a `WHERE` clause, it might help a bit.