# Order by most occurrences of search query

Tags: mysql

I want to search in a table in the fields **title** and **text** via search query and the rows with the most matches win.
My table **pages** looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------
| id | title      | text        | status |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | test test  | test xx     | 200    |
| 2  | nothing    | nothing     | 200    |
| 3  | test test  | test test   | 200    |
| 4  | abcefgh    | ijkl test   | 200    |
| 5  | test       | test abc    | 200    |
------------------------------------------
```

The expected result would look like this (selecting **id**, **title**, **text** via search query **test** and the limit 3):

```
---------------------------------
| id | title      | text        |
---------------------------------
| 3  | test test  | test test   |
| 1  | test test  | test xx     |
| 5  | test       | test abc    |
---------------------------------
```

I would really appreciate your help as I could not find a solution for a longer time now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try anything? A simple google search would solve your problem in 2 mins.

Comment: Yes, I searched - but in the wrong way unfortunately. I tried it in a different way now and found an answer. I honestly believed I would be the first one to ask this question. Thank you to forpas and Barmar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of occurrences of a string in a VARCHAR field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select
  id, title, text
from t
order by 
  round(length(title) - length(replace(title, "test", "")) / length("test") + 
  round(length(text) - length(replace(text, "test", "")) / length("test")
  desc
limit 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get an SQL error when executing your query but I assume it is close to being correct. I use the length/replace part in the **select** now with creating a variable from it (which is then used in **order by**).