# SQL: How can I make a query to get the STRING that do not contain 3 letters 'r'?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, vagrant, dbeaver

**Example:**

wordrr -> *Incorrect* because it have 3 'r'

word --> *Correct* becouse it not have 3 'r'

Comment: `NOT LIKE '%r%r%r%'`

Comment: If that `N` might be variable, even something like this could work:`WHERE char_length(s)-char_length(replace(s, 'r', '')) < N`  might be safer (re: length .vs. char_length).

Comment: @JonArmstrong that works for r, but for non-ascii characters, use char_length, not length, since length is length in bytes.  example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8a2f5ea32469bb130ffa37de877f373c

Comment: @ysth Notice my edit to the comment.  :)

Comment: Already asked&answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344795/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-varchar-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to fetch those rows in which a specified column doesn't contain the character "r" 3 times.

Here is the code to count the occurrence of character "r".

```
SELECT (LENGTH(ColName) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ColName, 'r', '')))  as "R Count" from TableName;
```

Note: If LENGTH doesn't work, try using LEN.

Now in order to fetch rows which doesn't have character "r" occurring 3 times or more

```
SELECT * from TableName where (LENGTH(ColName) - LENGTH(REPLACE(ColName, 'r', '')))  < 3 ;
```

Also you can use:

```
SELECT * from TableName where (char_length(ColName) - char_length (REPLACE (ColName, 'r', '')))  <= 3 ;
```