# How to search string from large size table

Tags: mysql

I have a table employee with thousands data. I need search particular string from this table. How to write query for that Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: add your table definition

Comment: ...and show us some sample data please.

Comment: Possibly related question [Extract a search string in context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6221821/4519059) or [How can I manipulate MySQL fulltext search relevance to make one field more 'valuable' than another?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/547542/4519059) ;).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example

```
SELECT field_name 
FROM table_name 
WHERE = 'value'
```

Answer (score 0):

If one (or possibly more) column has a bulk text you can use full-text search ability of mysql (5.6 and above) to do that. It will speed up search operation very much. The Documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE articles ( 
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  title VARCHAR(200), 
  body TEXT, 
  FULLTEXT (title,body) 
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

SELECT id, title, body, 
  MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('database' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 
  FROM articles ORDER BY score DESC;
```